# Regular expressions (regex) - How to split a string by the first X digits appear in it?

Tags: python, regex

I've been struggling to find the right regex (Python) to cover my requirement:

I want to split a string according to the first place in which there are 6 digits.

For example -

```
stringA = 'abcdf123456789'
```

Will ideally be cut into -

```
StringB='abcdf123456'
StringC='789'
```

So far - This is the solution I came up with:

```
x = re.split("(?=[0-9])", stringA)
```

And than loop over the results while counting the chars.

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is not going to be possible via regex, it is too complicated of a state machine.

Comment: Will you always have 6 consecutive digits at the end of first capture group?

Comment: Yes @anubhava, there will always be 6 consecutive digits, but they might be followed by another string

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by the comment that it wouldn't be possible via regex. Though there could be better ways possibly, I'd say with the sample shown `(?<=\D\d{6})` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this code with 2 capture groups:

```sh
>>> import re
>>> stringA = 'abcdf123456789'
>>> [(stringB,stringC)] = re.findall(r'(.*?\d{6})(.*)', stringA)
>>> print (stringB)
abcdf123456
>>> print (stringC)
789
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
stringA = 'abcdf123456789'
result = re.split("(?<=[0-9]{6})",stringA,maxsplit=1)
print(result)
# ['abcdf123456', '789']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a lookbehind:

```
>>> stringA = 'abcdf123456789'
>>> re.split(r'(?<=\d{6})', stringA, maxsplit=1)
['abcdf123456', '789']
```

[Demo and explanation of the regex](https://regex101.com/r/qW3Wij/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can split on 6 digits with `maxsplit=1`, and capture the group you split on, then you can build your strings easily:

```
import re

stringA = 'abcdf123456789'
split = re.split(r'(\d{6})', stringA, maxsplit=1)
# split is now ['abcdf', '123456', '789']
stringB = ''.join(split[:2])
stringC = split[2]

print(stringB)
print(stringC)

# abcdf123456
# 789
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

stringA = 'abcdf123456789'
index = re.search(r'\d{6}', stringA).end()
stringB = stringA[:index]
stringC = stringA[index:]
```

Comment: Please always provide an explanation to your code, why is it better than other solutions and how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `findall()` and `groups aka '()'` and simply finds the things you need!

```
import re

stringA = 'abcdf123456789'
pattern = r"([\D]*\d{6})(.*)"

result = re.findall(pattern, stringA)
print(result)
#output [('abcdf123456', '789')]
```